# HTML data structure in IE

Tags: html-table

I have the following table for image gallery that does not render well in IE but appears fine in Mozilla Firefox.

The problem is that images gallery scrolls all the way horizontally beyond the boundary instead of splitting into the next row.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

include("includes/config_gallery.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY cobjecttype ORDER BY cobjecttype";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["cobjecttype"]."'".($row["cobjecttype"]==$_REQUEST["cobjecttype"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["cobjecttype"]."</option>";
    }


 $count = 0;

if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (ctitle LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR csubject LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}

if ($_REQUEST["ref"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (creference LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["ref"])."%')";
}

if ($_REQUEST["cobjecttype"]<>'') {
    $search_cobjecttype = " AND cobjecttype='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["cobjecttype"])."'";  
}
if ($_REQUEST["cartist"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (cartist LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["cartist"])."%')";
}

if ($_REQUEST["cyear"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE cyear = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["cyear"])."'".$search_string.$search_cobjecttype;
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE c_id>0".$search_string.$search_cobjecttype;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    $c_id=$row['c_id'];
?>
    <td valign=top> 

    <table width=150 border=0 align=left class=allborder> 
    <tr> 
    <td width=70 bgcolor=#eee><a href="details.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id; ?>" > <?php echo $row['ctitle']; ?> </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><a href=details.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?> ><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['cfilename']; ?>" width="90" height="120" alt="" /></a>
        </td> 
    </tr> 

    </table>

 <?php $count++; 
  if ($count %8 == 0 && $count < $num) {
?>
 <tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </tr>
 </td>


<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<font color=red>No results found.</font>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Please, help.

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IE specific CSS that would give a max-width to the area the photo gallery is in.

```
IE6 css specific

* html ‪#‎div‬ { 
height: 300px;
}

IE7 css specific

*+html #div { 
height: 300px;
}

IE7&8 css specific (also seems to work in 10, haven't tested it in 9

#div {
height: 300px\9;
}
```